# Confusing start menu in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

The start menu on my laptop with Windows 10 is super confusing, since it contains plenty of icons that refer to software that is not even installed. This might have something to do with the laptop manufacturer who "sold" the space there as advertisement.

What is the best way to configure Windows 10 so that the Start menu follows the philosophy from previous versions, i.e. it only contain references to software that is actually installed?

Comment: Use an alternative like [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/).

Comment: Being we are only talking about a handful of icons, is there any reason you can’t right click them and uninstall / remove them?

Comment: Well to be fair there’s more like three handful. ;) Some are only links, others are actually installed. The slow context menu doesn’t help either.

Comment: If they're unwanted games etc., just uninstall them. Some of the included Windows apps must be removed using PowerShell. Also, use a third-party tool such as ShutUp10 to remove ads.

Comment: Go to Settings\Personalization\Start\Turn off "Show suggestions occasionally in Start" to turn off the AD

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like you got a new PC or just installed Windows 10.
After connecting to internet just remove them unpinning from start menu. And don't forget to disable occasional suggestion on start menu personalise setting.

[image]